# Woher kommt "Bratze"?

Tags: etymology

*Bratze* ist ein abwertender Begriff für Frauen. DWDS nennt keine Etymologie dazu.

Was bedeutet es und aus welchen Begriffen hätte es sich die Bedeutung ehemals entwickeln können?

Comment: https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=eine%2BBratze&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou

Comment: "Weib" ist selbst bereits ein abwertender Begriff. Daher habe ich in deiner Frage "Weiber" durch "Frauen" ersetzt.

Comment: @Roland, aha, und wer oder was ist "Honnen"? Niederländisch *Bratzen* mit englisch *brat* zu vergleichen funktioniert auch nicht ohne weiteres. Mit hochdeutscher Lautverschiebung und Entlehnung ins Niederländische ginge das vielleicht. Daher ist der Verweis auf Niederländisch erstmal nur eine faule Ausrede. Insbesondere die Behauptung, das kein Zusammenhang mit *bracchia* bestehe, ist nur so lala. Eine verlässliche Quelle ist das nicht.

Comment: Übrigens hatte ich an jene Seite gedacht und dann nicht nachgeschaut, weil eine Redewendung ist *Bratze* eigentlich nicht. Quellenangabe ist sogar vorhanden, *Honnen, Peter: Wo kommt dat her? Herkunftswörterbuch der Umgangssprache an Rhein und Ruhr. Greven Verlag Köln, 2018.*

Answer (score -2):

Ich kannte diese Bedeutung dieses Wortes bisher nicht. Dort wo ich lebe (im Osten Österreichs) bezeichnet man mit *Bratze* nur eine besonders große Hand eines Menschen oder die Vorderpfote eines Tieres, und das auch nur umgangssprachlich. Häufiger ist die Schreibweise mit *P* (Pratze). Ein Synonym dafür ist *Pranke,* und im Fall der Tierpfote auch *Tatze.* *Bratze,* in dieser Bedeutung, ist ein Lehnwort, das vor rund 400 Jahren aus dem Italienischen ins Deutsche gekommen ist (italienisch *»braccio«* = Arm). Dieses italienische Wort wiederum entstand aus dem lateinischen Wort *»brachium«* oder *»bracchium«,* was ebenfalls *»Arm«* oder *»Unterarm«*  bedeutet.

Aber all das hat nichts Abwertendes an sich und bezeichnet nur einen Körperteil und keinen ganzen Menschen. Daher habe ich gegoogelt, und von entscheidender Bedeutung war der Link, den Roland als Kommentar unter die Frage gepostet hat.

Der abwertende Begriff für Menschen, meist für Frauen, manchmal auch für nervige Kinder, hat mit der Pranke genau gar nichts zu tun. Die beiden Wörter »Bratze = große Hand« und »Bratze = aufgetakelte nervige Frau« sind waschechte Homonyme, also Wörter, die zwar gleich geschrieben und ausgesprochen werden, aber unterschiedliche Bedeutung und Herkunft haben.

Auf der Seite [Redensartenindex](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=eine+Bratze&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou&sp2=erl_ou&sp3=bsp_ou&sp4=erg_ou) wird auf das Buch [Wo kommt dat her?](https://shop.greven-verlag.de/wo-kommt-dat-her.html) von Peter Honnen als Quelle für folgende Aussage verwiesen:

> In der hier genannten Bedeutung ist das Wort wohl erst Ende des 20. Jahrhunderts entstanden. Zur Herkunft verweist Honnen auf das Niederdeutsche und Mittelniederländische. "Bratzen" oder "pratzen" kann in den Mundarten schmollen oder protzen bedeuten, ...

Der Satz geht weiter, bezieht sich dann aber auf andere Quellen:

> ... in neuerer Zeit aber auch den Klang von lauten E-Gitarren. Im alten Niederländischen bedeutete "brat" wild, unbeherrschbar, Englisch "brat" bedeutet Göre oder Quälgeist.

Ein Teil der Bedeutung scheint also vom Niederländischen *»brat«* oder *»bratzen«* zu kommen (wild und unbeherrscht sein, protzig sein, dabei aber schmollen). Aber vor allem dann, wenn man damit Kinder bezeichnet, scheint sich auch die Bedeutung des englischen Wortes *»brat«* dazu zu mischen. Also habe ich auch dieses Wort recherchiert:

Das englische Wort *»brat«,* mit dem nervige Kinder bezeichnet werden (vergleichbar mit dem deutschen Wort *»Göre«,* das aber nur auf Mädchen anwendbar ist, während das englische *»brat«* geschlechtsneutral ist) stammt aus der Zeit rund um das Jahr 1500 und bedeutete ursprünglich *»Kind eines Bettlers; bettelndes Kind«,* was vermutlich vom Wort *»bratchet«* aus der Sprache Scots abgeleitet wurde und mit dem altfranzösischen *»brachet«* verwandt ist. (Scots »*»bratchet«* und altfranzösisch *»brachet«* bedeuten beide *Hündin* oder *Jagdhund*)

Comment: Das ist alles ganz tolle Kopierpastete. Eine Auseinandersetzung mit dem niederländischen Wortfeld wäre jedoch wünschenswert gewesen. Ein klares Bild ergibt sich somit nicht. Insbesondere ist eine kurze Bewertung der Quellen erforderlich. Mir fallen dafür leider nur brachiale Kraftausdrücke ein, deswegen bitte ich ja um fachgerechte Hilfe. Außerdem kann mit *protzen*, falls das dazu gehört, durchaus ein Zusammenhang mit idiom. *sich aufbrezeln* vermutet werden, von dem du vermutlich auch noch nie gehört hast, das dem Anschein nach zu *Brezel*, also auch zu *bracchium* gezählt werden dürfte.