# Woher kommt der Begriff "Brett" im Gamer Jargon?

Tags: etymology, colloquial, gaming

Gibt's eine Erklärung für die Nutzung des Begriffs *Brett* ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFdhr4amydc&ab_channel=xPaintedBlack&t=12s)) im Gamer Jargon, speziell bei Ego-Shootern?

> Alter was hat der denn für'n Brett kassiert? Der war einfach im Sprung, Junge.

Unter dem Begriff versteht man einen eindrucksvollen Schuss, der den Gegner meistens sofort tötet (üblicherweise ein Headshot oder ein Flickshot).

DWDS listet keine Erklärung dazu (wobei es die Frage erweckt, warum es einen Stein im Brett haben heißt). Ebenso wenig Wiktionary.

Comment: Die Formulierung gibt es nicht nur im Gamer-Jargon, siehe z. B. [Söder bezeichnete das Programm als 'echtes Brett'](https://www.n-tv.de/politik/CDU-und-CSU-einigen-sich-auf-echtes-Brett-article22633654.html) oder [Der Rothaarsteig-Marathon ist ein echtes Brett](https://www.laufendessen.de/der-rothaarsteig-marathon-ein-echtes-brett-im-sauerlaender-wald/). Ich würde eher in Richtung "allgemeine" Jugendsprache, vielleicht ein paar Generationen zurück, denken. Vielleicht ist der Bezug tatsächlich einfach das Bild, mit einem Stück Holz eine übergezimmert zu bekommen.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck interessanter Punkt!

Answer (score 4):

Das ist kein spezieller Gamer-Jargon, sondern "allgemeine Jugendsprache" (wobei "Jugend" hier schon ziemlich erweitert zu verstehen ist, auch in meiner Jugend Anfang der 80er des letzten Jahrhunderts war der Begriff durchaus schon gängig).

Ursprünglich bezog sich der Begriff alleine auf physische Gewalt:

> Wills't 'n Brett?

war die (möglicherweise scherzhafte) Drohung, dass der andere dabei ist, zu weit zu gehen und eine Androhung physischer Gewalt, sollte er weitermachen.

> ein Brett (ab)kriegen

ist auf der anderen Seite der Ausdruck dafür, dass jemand "die volle Ladung" abbekommen hat und eben auf der falschen Seite dieser Auseinandersetzung stand.

Zunehmend höre ich den Ausdruck auch für allgemeine nicht-physische Auseinandersetzungen, wie in

> "Wo ist Peter?" - "Der ist beim Rektor und holt sich sein Brett ab."

wo es nicht um physische Gewalt, sondern um eine Zurechtweisung durch eine Autoritätsperson geht.

In gängigen Wörterbüchern habe ich dazu allerdings nichts gefunden. Ich persönlich habe dabei weniger das Bild im Kopf, dass jemand mit dem Brett "eine überzogen" bekommt, sondern eher, dass er mit dem Kopf gegen ein über den Weg genageltes Brett läuft.

Comment: Ist das ein regional unterschiedliches Phänomen?

Comment: Nun, ich kenne es nur aus meiner Umgebung, also Südwestdeutschland, Bayern und Nordrhein-Westfalen.

Comment: Schöne Erklärung! Ob es sich nur um Jugendsprache handelt, bin ich nicht sicher. Dazu folgende Anekdote: Anfang der neunziger Jahre erzählte mir ein befreundeter Rechtsanwalt, dass er in einem Strafprozess einen älteren Mandanten vertrete, der nach ausgiebigem Alkoholgenuss in einer Kneipe unvermittelt einem anderen Gast einen Schlag ins Gesicht versetzte - mit den Worten "Jetzt kriegst Du ein Brett". Könnte also auch ein regionales Dimng sein (hier in Hessen).

Comment: Hier noch ein Google-Fund aus Österreich: https://www.derstandard.at/story/1304552123170/brett.

Comment: "Ursprünglich bezog sich der Begriff alleine auf physische Gewalt:" - eine Behauptung ohne Beleg. Wann und wo war denn dieser Ursprung? 2019? 1950? 1620?

Answer (score 0):

Eine anscheinend noch nicht geäußerte Vermutung ist der Zusammenhang zu [DWDS: Dünnbrettbohrer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/D%C3%BCnnbrettbohrer). Außer den dünnen, nicht ernst zu nehmenden Brettern gibt es noch die **dicken Bretter**, die *echten Bretter* könnten das Adjektiv von den *echten Problemen* übernommen haben, was zumindest auf die die von Henning erwähnten Beispiele, die nicht aus dem Gaming-Bereich stammen, passt.

Comment: Vielleicht noch einen Abstecher über die Bretter, die die Welt bedeuten?

Answer (score -5):

***Brett*** ist vorrangig aus der Musik bekannt, dort schon vor mindestens zwanzig Jahren im Hip-Hop-Jargon gelesen. Dieses Meme ist inzwischen so häufig, dass die Verwendung im Gamer-Jargong zweifelslos davon beeinflusst ist

Es könnte meiner bescheidenen Meinung nach als Wortspiel für *Platte* verstanden werden, entsprechend älterem englisch *bord* "plate" (siehe da en.Wiktionary).

Der jüngeren Generation ist *Schallplatte* vermutlich kein konkreter Begriff mehr. Im Nachtklub-Betrieb war diese bis zu den  Napster-Jahren noch das häufigste Medium. In den letzten Jahren war "mehr Bretter als ein Baumarkt" ein häufiger Kommentar unter Musikvideos beliebter Künstler. Der Berliner Rapper Obi One bezieht sich bei der Namenswahl offensichtlich ambivalent auf eine Variante des Memes, die den Baumarkt Obi als Symbol erkennen lässt. Der Berliner Rapper *Rilla* hat mit dem Titel *Schwarze Barretas* ein komplizierteres Wortspiel gewagt. Bei Takt77, *Schwarze Augen*, ist der Bezug überhaupt nicht mehr erkennbar.

Dem vorrausgehend ist vielleich *Billboard Charts* zu bedenken. Um diese blose Vermutung zu bestätigen, bedürfte es jedoch eines entsprechenden Kompositums im Deutschen oder eines entsprechenden Clipping schon im Englischen. Zumindest im Internet Jargon hat sich inzwischen *Brett* für “Forum” etabliert, eingedeutscht aus *BBS* “Bulletin Board Sytem”, kurz *board*, das einen ähnlichen Vorgang vermuten lässt und vielleicht sogar älter ist. Jedenfalls war dieser *Bill-Board* kaum jemandem im deutschsprachigen Raum ein Begriff, wurde hauptsächlich im US zentrischen Musikprogramm unverändert als Eigenname übernommen.

Darüber hinaus gibt es natürlich das Verb *brettern*, das weiterer Erklärung bedarf. Eine Analogiebildung zu *brutzeln, bretzeln* usw. wäre denkbar. Auf neuenglisch spricht man schließlich auch von einem Börner, zu deutsch unter anderem von einem *Dauerbrenner*. Da dieser Slang nicht der Literatursprache angehört, sind Belege jedenfalls nicht belastbar; Homophonie ausreichende Motivation.

Gänzlich unwahrscheinlich, wegen des Wortlauts doch beachtenswert, worauf auch die Redensart "hat so einen Bart" anspielen könnte, wäre *Barde*: "entlehnt (16. Jh.) aus lat. *bardus*, einem Wort kelt. Herkunft (gall. *bardd* ‘Dichter’)." (Pfeifer/DWDS). Vgl. englisch *bars* (“Takte”).

Auf französisch spricht man auch vom *interpret*, dem laut englischem Wiktionary lateinisch *pretium* ("preis") voraus geht, das dann wegen der Bedeutung des gesuchten Worts wohl maßgeblich sein müsste. Auf Deutsch spricht man gelegentlich noch vom *Marktschreier*, der die Preise *verlautbart*, bzw. im übertragenen Sinne *veranschlagt* bis ein Käufer den *Zuschlag* erhält. Auf Englisch wiederum spricht man von *barter* (d.h. handeln *wie auf dem Bazar*).

Ob deswegen auch "der letzte Schrei", quasi als "ein Stein im Brett", entstanden wäre, und ob dies über niederländische Beziehungen odet jüdisch-deutsch geführte Schallplattenverlage in den USA mit *Bill Board* in Berührung gekommen ist, ist nicht zu entscheiden.

---

Der **billboard** im eigentlichen Sinne wäre wohl laut en.Wiktionary:

- 1. "A very large outdoor sign, generally used for advertising."

  Einfach ein Plakat. In diesem Bereich denkt man eher an *Schild* (etwa *Schildermaler*).
- 2. "(dated) A flat surface, such as a panel or fence, on which bills are posted; a bulletin board."

  Ein sogenanntes *schwarzes Brett* (d.h. für öffentlichen Aushang bestimmte Fläche). Tatsächlich bedeutet englisch *blackboard* "Tafel". Siehe dazu "in der Kreide bei jemandem stehen", vergleich englisch *bill* "Rechnung".

  Weil *Calculation* "Rechnung, Steinchen" mit *calx* "Sandstein" erklärt wird, wozu auch *Kalk* und englisch *chalk* "Kreide" zählen, ist die Redewendung “einen Stein im Brett bei jemandem haben” eigentlich offensichtlich (s. aber Pfeifer, unten).
- 3. "(nautical) A piece of thick plank, armed with iron plates, and fixed on the bow or fore-channels of a vessel, for the bill or fluke of the anchor to rest on."

  Viel zu technisch um den gesuchten Begriff zu erläutern, allemal wegen des Metiers auf ältere Herkunft einzuschätzen. Altnordisch kennt einen ähnlichen Begriff (s. Boutkan, Old Frisian Etymological Dictionary: “bord”).

  Siehe ferner *volle Breitseite*.

(weiteres unter https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/billboard)

Außerdem bedeutet *bill* zoologisch auch "Schnabel" (ferner *schnäbli*, daher wohl *Billy Boy*, vgl. *Praeservativ*). Den Eigennamen erklärt das nicht.

Etwas einfacher betrachtet, kann man vielleicht an die *Messlatte* denken. Dementsprechen kann zum *yard stick* "Zollstock" auch *sticky note* bemerkt werden, vergleich deutsch *Stichpunkt*, *Steckbrief*, englisch *bullet point*, *item* ...

---

***Bart*** ist althochdeutsch für ein Schwert, eine Axt,  Herkunft unsicher (*barta, parta* [EWA]).

Offensichtlich gehört genau dorthin der von @tofro besprochene Bedeutungsraum: *willst'n Brett*, "die (möglicherweise scherzhafte) Drohung, dass der andere dabei ist, zu weit zu gehen und eine Androhung physischer Gewalt, sollte er weitermachen."

Die Herkunft des althochdeutschen Begriffs ist allerdings unsicher (eventuell zu *Brand*, was auch Schwert bedeuten konnte), Anschluss an *Brett* ebenso.

Andererseits ist *bill* etymologisch zu *Beil* zu stellen. Das schlägt alles in dieselbe Richtung, ist jedoch zu weit weg. So ist etwa *Peil*, bzw. *Pegel* (i.S.v. *Messstand*, *Messlate*, *Aufzeichnung*) mangels Lautgesetzen nicht sicher mit *bill* zu vergleichen.

Siehe außerdem die vertretbare Behauptung im Duden Herkunftswörterbuch, *laden* gehörte vielleicht zu *Lade*, *Einladung*, *Schublade* und *Ladengeschäft*, weil diese aus Holz gefertigt worden seien, also *Laden* "Brett". Auch dazu passt @Tofro's Behauptung: *ein Brett (ab)kriegen*, "ist auf der anderen Seite der Ausdruck dafür, das jemand "die volle Ladung" abbekommen hat". Dabei ist *Ladung* im Sinne von *Munition* passender Weise mit *Ladung* als protokollierte Aufstellung mitgeführter Güter zu verstehen; ähnlich auch *Charta*, vgl. *Vollkaracho* mit anderem Ableitungssuffix. Ebenso ist *Pritsche* (d.h. Ladefläche des Wagens, auch Sitzbank, Liege) wohl von Brett abgeleitet. Geschnittene Bretter sind selbst aber auch Ware (wie eingangs angedeutet).

<sub>Im Umkehrschluss ist ein Einfluss des von @tofro angeführten Bedeutungsraumes im Musik-Jargon anzunehmen, im Gamer-Jargon sogar maßgeblich. Wie sich die Begriffe im Detail gegenseitig beeinflussen, ist kaum auszumachen. Bspw. stehen *Hit* bzw. *Brett* sonst in keinem Zusammenhang.</sub>

In der Metrologie ist alles Relativ, nur das Urmaß nicht. In der Etymologie verhält es sich nicht anders, allerdings stellen Sprachwissenschaftler allerlei maßlose Behauptungen auf.

Siehe übrigens *Bulle* aus lateinisch *bulla*, ist auch im deutschen ein Begriff. Die Herkunft ist letztendlich ungewiss. Dem modernen Begriff liegt ein Verständnis des Runden zu Grunde, das sich auch in *Ball* niederschlägt, *mit geballter Kraft*, sowie in der üblichen Zeichensetzung für ...

- 1. ... Bullet Points
- 2. ?????
- 3. Profit.

Da die Etymologie aber so unsicher ist, zieht das alles zuvorgesagte runter, nämlich auf den Boden der Tatsachen. Nichts genaues weiß man nicht.

---

Zu guterletzt sei Pfeifer zitiert:

> Zu *Brett* ‘Spielbrett’ gehört *einen (guten) Stein* im Brett haben ‘in Gunst stehen’ (15. Jh.). –

> [“Brett” in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al., Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (1993)]

Eine Quelle wird dort jedoch nicht angegeben. Dem Prinzip folge ich also.

Ursprünglich soll *Brett* zu *bohren* gehört haben. Das passt zumindest zu Hieb- und Stichwaffen.

Um eine verbindliche Antwort zu geben, lege ich mich also auf *barter* fest (s. o.). Laut einer Theorie stammt dies aus **altnordisch *barátta*** (“contest”, isländisch "(uncountable) fight, struggle"), von *berja* (“to beat, strike”), so en.Wiktionary; mit urgermanisch **barjaną* < urindogermanisch **bʰerH-* besteht Wurzelverwandschaft mit *Brett*, *Barren*, *bohren*, vielleicht.

> Unsicher ist, ob folgende Wörter von *bor, burien* abgeleitet sind oder zu althochdeutsch *bar*², *berzo* (s. d. d.) mit an-
> derer Ablautstufe gehören: mhd., nhd. mdartl. (obd.)
> *borzen, porzen* ‚emporragen, hervorstehen usw.‘ (<
> **boratjan*; **vgl. altenglisch *borettan* ‚[ein Schwert] schwingen‘**,
> → *-azzen*), wie auch nhd. *Bürzel* ‚Steiß eines Vogels‘
> neben *Berzel* ‚dss.‘.

(“bor” in: Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Althochdeutschen, Lloyd, Lühr *et al.*, Bd. 2 (1996))

Es heißt jedoch viel häufiger "willst du ein *paar* (auf's Maul)?", nicht *enbor* oder wie oben bei @tofro *ein Brett*. Stimmloses p ist in *empor* belegt, das wohl auch dazu zählt. Zudem lässt sich *bor* als Adverb nachweisen (bei woerterbuch netz: “bor”). Das war hier auch schonmal Thema (s. *boah ey*). Weil Fäuste paarweise auftreten, ist das unterspezifierte **H* vermutlich als Dual-Endung **-h<sub>1</sub>(e)* zu identifizieren. Das Verhältnis zu den anderen Ableitungen erklärt das nicht.

*Paar* wird ansonsten aus lateinisch *pār* hergeleitet. Dessen Herkunft ist leider ungewiss.

Siehe übrigens *Bratze* "Pranke" ([Woher kommt "Bratze"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/75264/35977)).

Siehe auch schweizerisch *Barat* “Wechsel”, mlat. *barata, baratum*, mhd. *pārāt* "Wechsel, Tausch, Betrug" wie engl. *barter*.

Außerdem unter *Bâreteⁿ* / *Barneteⁿ* 
"ein Barren, eine Krippe voll (Futter);" *barreten* "dem Vieh das Futter (in den Barren) geben":

> *bildl.* Den han-ich schön abg'suferet [*Dem hab ich gehörig meine Meinung gesag*], **Der het en B.** und wird wol es Wiltschi schwigen.

(Idiotikon: [“Bareten“](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/p/lem/161386), dort mit Diakritika)

Comment: Danke für diese sehr lange und gewundene Reise durch das Reich der Assoziation, Spekulation und Sprachspielereien. Natürlich kann ich nur für mich sprechen, aber ich kann dir und deinen Ausführungen nicht mit Überzeugung folgen, geschweige denn eine klare Antwort auf die Frage finden. Ob das an mir oder der Antwort liegt, überlasse ich der Einschätzung der anderen geneigten Leser.

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Meinung, @Stephie. Natürlich kannst auch nur du für dich eine Antwort auf die Frage finden. Das hängt wohl mit dem Thema zusammen und nicht so sehr mit der Anti-Antwort. Schön wenn du dich nicht mit weniger zufrieden gibst.